# Python: Command works in Terminal, not os.system()

Tags: python, nltk

I'm writing a Python script to pull PDFs from a website, loop over them, scrape their text, and then perform basic natural language processing on them.

I'm running into a strange problem: if I use [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/)'s `pdf2txt.py` command in Terminal, it works fine. If instead I try to loop over my files in the script itself, like so:

```
for url in papers:
     urllib.urlretrieve(url, DIR + "paper.pdf")
     os.system("pdf2text.py -o paper.txt -t text paper.pdf")
```

I get the following error:

> sh: pdf2text.py: command not found

Is it something to do with PATH, env vars? I don't even know where to begin.

I'd really prefer `pdf2txt` than, say, [`slate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate), since the latter's causing `nltk` to bug out (whole other SO post, I guess).

Comment: It definitely looks like a `PATH` issue. Use the absolute path to the script.

Comment: Don't you need "**python** pdf2text.py -o paper.txt -t text paper.pdf"

Comment: aren't you missing the call to python? `"python pdf2text.py -o paper.txt -t text paper.pdf" `

Comment: @David, @Lucas:  I know it seems like it would need the python call, but the installation script of `pdf2txt` creates a program `/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the program name is `pdf2txt.py`, not `pdf2text.py`.

Comment: Oh my Lord, I hang my head in shame.

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us sometimes :)